# how to add gps data to image, flutter image_picker Android

Tags: android, flutter, dart

No gps data added to flutter image_picker image

```
final pickedFile = await imagePicker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
final bytes = await pickedFile.readAsBytes();
final tags = await readExifFromBytes(bytes);
print("Tags : $tags ");
```

Tags: (No Gps data)

```
{Image ImageWidth: 4624, Image Model: Redmi Note 8 Pro, Image ImageLength: 3472, Image Orientation: Rotated 90 CW, Image DateTime: 2020:11:15 18:15:14, Image ExifOffset: 142, Image Make: Xiaomi, EXIF FNumber: 189/100, EXIF FocalLength: 543/100, EXIF ExposureTime: 50003/1000000, EXIF Flash: Flash did not fire, EXIF ISOSpeedRatings: 3750, EXIF ExifImageLength: 3472, EXIF ExifImageWidth: 4624, EXIF ApertureValue: 46/25, EXIF ShutterSpeedValue: -431/100, EXIF SubSecTime: 530}
```

btw it didn't asked me to allow location while taking pic(first time), do i have to add any permission ?

Comment: What's does its meaning, your need a location for pic. Or only location at the time of click a pic

Comment: need location of pic, pics taken by default camera app add location data to image.

Comment: @invariant, was you able to complete your question? Could you post your solution?

Comment: @invariant did you solved this? I have this same problem. Flutter Web using image_picker does show the GPS data. But the same file using image_picker on a real Android (samsung) device does not show the GPS data. Im using metadata package to read the exif tags

Answer (score 2):

1. If you need image locations gallery as well as camera,
   See this link.

[Is possible to get Image GPS location coordinates from the Image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55059980/is-possible-to-get-image-gps-location-coordinates-from-the-image)

Or
I have one custome option also if this suitable for you.

2. If only needs location at the time of camera pic image.that opens by your app,

Use easy way like

```
File _image; 
final picker = ImagePicker();

 Future getImage() async { 
final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

 setState(() {
 if (pickedFile != null) {

// your will take user location  at this time
 _image = File(pickedFile.path); 
    }
 else { 
    print('No image selected.');
    }
 });
```

Comment: thanks for reply, may be i am not clear in my question. pics  taken using image picker didn't added gps data to image, see tags output above. Usually when we take a pic camera show a dialog "do you want to allow location"  that didn't happened on my phone ,but i got that pop up while running in emulator.

Answer (score 2):

This is what we use to add the GPS info:

```
      final picker = ImagePicker();

      picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera).then((pickedFile) async {
        var myImagePath = coreNotifier.myCurrentPath.absolute.path;

        final exif =
            dd.FlutterExif.fromBytes(await pickedFile!.readAsBytes());

        Position position = await _determinePosition();

        await exif.setLatLong(position.latitude, position.longitude);
        await exif.saveAttributes();

        final modifiedImage = await exif.imageData;
        var imageName = "imgName..";
        File imageFile = new File("$myImagePath/$imageName.jpg");
        imageFile.writeAsBytes(
          List.from(modifiedImage!),
        );
        coreNotifier.reload();
      });
```

Also using this packages:

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:flutter_exif_plugin/flutter_exif_plugin.dart' as dd;
```